# USB Hidden files

Tags: windows-7

A number of files and folders show up on the screen when I plug my usb drive into a different computer. But when I plug it into my computer, I only see "regular" files and folders. What can I do to see the hidden files on my computer?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to guess you are using Windows 7

Click Organize>Folder and search Options>View and check "Show hidden folders, files, and drives".

but it is very similar for XP.

Click Tools>Folder and search Options>View and check "Show hidden folders, files, and drives".

Comment: command-line analogy: `dir /ah` shows **only** hidden files

Answer (score 2):

You may also try this simple windows script for unhiding files and directories. It only prompts the user to input the drive letter then executes the vbscript.

Run your notepad, copy the code below, then save it as **unhide.vbs**

```
pc_drive = InputBox("Input drive letter" & vbnewline & "example: E:\", "Drive","E:\")
ryt = Right(pc_drive,2)
   If Len(pc_drive) <> 3 or ryt <> ":\" Then
   Call MsgBox("Either your input was invalid or the drive you specified doesn'texist",vbokonly,"Error")
End If

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
ShowSubfolders FSO.GetFolder(pc_drive)

Sub ShowSubFolders(Folder)
   str =""
   For Each Subfolder in Folder.SubFolders
      str =str & " " & Subfolder.Path
      subFolder.Attributes = 0
      ShowSubFolders Subfolder
   Next
End Sub
```

You could save it in your USB drive for more accessibility. Instruction how to use it can be found in the link below.

[Windows Script For Unhiding Folders Hidden By Worm Virus](https://sites.google.com/site/teachmemrxymon/fix-windows-mess/script-to-unhide-folders-hidden-by-worm)

**EDIT:** provided the vbscript code.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. I'll edit my answer in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

Control Panel. Under the View tab in Folder Options, unhide what you want to see by unchecking the appropriate boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Some people actually prefer hidden files and folders staying invisible. If you don't want to change the **global setting** like KCotreau suggested, you may be better off using a free alternative file manager like [FreeCommander](http://www.freecommander.com/) or [Xplorer2](http://zabkat.com/) to go after hidden files/folders. This way you can still use the file manager you're used to and retain the ability to block hidden files/folders from view. Most of the Windows Explorer replacements are also available in a portable flavor.

If you're into AutoHotkey you may also want to take a look at a small script featured over at [howtogeek.com](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/keyboard-ninja/keyboard-ninja-toggle-hidden-files-with-a-shortcut-key-in-windows/) (Show & Hide hidden files on demand in Windows). This script allows you to use <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to quickly toggle hidden files.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to guess you are using Windows 7

Click Organize>Folder and search Options>View and check "Show hidden folders, files, and drives".

but it is very similar for XP.

Click Tools>Folder and search Options>View and check "Show hidden folders, files, and drives".

All uncheck three checkbox after "**Show hidden folders, files, and drives**".