# View hidden files/folders on windows phone?

Tags: windows-7, command-line

I have a Windows Phone, and when I connect it to my pc, I can only see files such as music, pictures, music, etc.

I already enabled the ability to see hidden files, but I still can only see the standard files. I want to see all of them - OS and all.

Program command lines, whatever, would be helpful.

Comment: What are you attempting to achieve? To my best knowledge WP is intentionally hardened to prevent anything more than dumb media access.

Comment: Need to attempt files from pc, not from phone

Comment: Try this link on my answer

http://superuser.com/questions/311947/usb-hidden-files/311951#311951

Comment: You mentioned you enabled hidden files. Did you enable OS files as per @Alamakanambra's answer?

Comment: This is really a Windows Phone question, not a PC question; the PC is just presenting what the phone reveals to it over MTP. Suggest moving it to http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 2):

You need to go to control panel -> folder options -> view tab -> uncheck Hide protected operation system files

[image: folder options]